# Override global label font-size with my own css class?

Tags: css

I'm trying to update a website. There's a label element I want to style. It looks like:

```
 #foo {
     font-size: 9px;
 }

 <label id="foo"></label>
```

but it looks like a css definition for the "label" element is overriding the more specific style I'm setting. I'm seeing this in firebug

```
label {
    font-size: 16px;
}
.foo {
    font-size: 9px; /* strikethrough on my font-size declaration here */
}
```

so is there a way to override the default label font-size setting without modifying it for everything? (I thought my more specific definition would do that by default)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mixed up the syntax for `id` with the one for `class`:

```
#foo { /* # = id, . = class */
    font-size: 9px;
}
```

Keep in mind that `id`s are supposed to be unique for the entire document

or switch your label to using a class instead:

```
<label class="foo"></label>
```

Comment: #id is [more specific](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) that tag and thus prevails.

Comment: `.class` is also more specific than tag (element).

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the `!important` indicator to give precedence to the rule.

```
font-size: 9px !important;
```

Comment: Ah that's what !important does.